# MUI v5: BottomNavigationAction with StyledBadge Icon?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In Material-UI v4, I could do a `StyledBadge` in a `BottomNavigationAction` like this:

```
<BottomNavigationAction
    id="0"
    label="Appointments"
    icon={(
        <StyledBadge badgeContent={numberOfUnreadAPPTS.toString()} overlap="circular">
            <ApptsIcon />
        </StyledBadge>
   )}
    classes={{
        root: classes.actionItemStyles,
        selected: classes.selected
    }}
    disabled={!AppState.netWorkIsOnline}
/>
```

In MUI v5 I tried to do it like this:

```
<BottomNavigationAction label="Appointments" icon={
    <StyledBadge badgeContent={numberOfUnreadAPPTS.toString()} >
        <ApptsIcon />
    </StyledBadge>
} />
```

...but it's not liking the use of `StyledBadge` for the icon:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

What's the correct way to get a `StyledBadge` in `BottomNavigationAction` in MUI v5?

Comment: Not reproducible: https://codesandbox.io/s/simplebottomnavigation-material-demo-forked-vyb0f?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: it's working in the above sandbox

Comment: Thanks very much, @NearHuscarl.  The CodeSandBox showed me what I needed to get this working.  If you'd like to post a link to the CodeSandBox as the answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @VikR what's the issue though? did you import the wrong way? because you doesn't show that part of code, I don't understand why it works since I copied the code directly from your question.

Comment: @NearHuscarl, somewhere I'd gotten the notion that there was a new `StyledBadge` component in mui v5. Second, I'd used a feature of my IDE to auto-generate an import statement for `StyledBadge`, and it had created one, confirming my incorrect impression that there was such a thing, so I had an empty object in the `StyledBadge` variable. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment, it turned out that @Vikr accidentally create an empty object because they thought the IDE would import a component called `StyledBadge`, which doesn't exist from MUI itself (probably a failed copy from [this](https://mui.com/components/badges/#customization) example) so it creates an empty object instead:

```
const StyledBadge = {};
```

As a result, when it's passed to the `icon` prop, MUI complains that `StyledBadge` is an object instead of a `ReactNode`:

```
<BottomNavigationAction
  icon={
    <StyledBadge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
      <ShoppingCartIcon />
    </StyledBadge2>
  }
```

Working code:

```
const StyledBadge = styled(Badge)<BadgeProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  '& .MuiBadge-badge': {
    right: -3,
    top: 13,
    border: `2px solid ${theme.palette.background.paper}`,
    padding: '0 4px',
  },
}));
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]